# How do I do "Reverse destructuring"

Tags: reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring, ecmascript-2016

We all know about destructuring objects in ES6+

```
const myObject = {name: 'John', age: 30, eyeColor: 'brown'}
const {name, age, eyeColor} = myObject
```

... is there a "cleaner" way to do the following?

```
const name = 'John'
const age = 30
const eyeColor = 'brown'

myObject.name = name
myObject.age = age
myObject.eyeColor = eyeColor
```

Not a great example but in some cases I have to do this with 18 or so variables and it's ugly. Is there an elegant method or utility to do this?

Comment: Where does `myObject` come from, does it already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you don't have to explicitly write out the value if the key and variable name are the same

```js
const myObject = {name, age, eyeColor}
```